# Swiftmailer: Missing space in subject email

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I'm using `SwiftMailer (v 4.2.2)` to send my emails, and I recently observed that when SwiftMailer construct an email, if it has a long subject, it inserts line breaks into it in the header of the mail.

**Subject**:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet =?iso-8859-1?Q?consect=E9tur?=
adipisicing elit
```

The original subject was : `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectétur adipisicing elit`

When I send the mail (using Mandrill, or even the php mailer with my local SMTP server), I receive the mail with the subject `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectéturadipisicing elit`

*The space is missing, just where the line break was inserted in the header*.

I tried the solution on this [thread](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/393) : removing the `\r` in the function `getTokenAsEncodedWord()` in `classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/AbstractHeader.php` , but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's not just because the subject is long but because of the special characters as well?

Comment: Yeah, but itappears that even if some characters are encoded like here, the subject is not broken if there is no line break inserted

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is an issue with how Swiftmailer is generating a subject line that has special characters, and how Mandrill's parser handles those. Specifically, it appears that the space before any line breaks after a special character will be removed by Mandrill.

The reason is that very often when the subject line header is split into two lines, the second line is indented by a single space, so this is likely why you're seeing the space be removed once Mandrill has parsed your message : swiftmailer only puts one single space at the second line of the header after a special character.

Changing the language does not always work for me.

At this moment, the simplest (but ugly) fix  is to change how Swiftmailer sends its header to Mandrill.

At *lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/AbstractHeader.php*, line 305
replacing

```
$header->setMaxLineLength(76)
```

by

```
$header->setMaxLineLength(998)
```

fixed everything for me.

Although the recommended max header size is 78 characters long, it is fine to go up to 998 characters (see [RFC 2822 section 2.2.3](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt))

Answer (score 0):

In their code they using lang

```
protected function getTokenAsEncodedWord($token, $firstLineOffset = 0)
{
    // Adjust $firstLineOffset to account for space needed for syntax
    $charsetDecl = $this->_charset;
    if (isset($this->_lang)) {
        $charsetDecl .= '*'.$this->_lang;
    }
```

Subject saving as Swift_Mime_Headers_UnstructuredHeader without lang, so its NULL there.

So I made working fix in Symfony 2:

```
$message->getHeaders()->get('subject')->setLanguage($this->container->get('session')->get('_locale', 'en'));
```

For you its smt like:

```
$message->getHeaders()->get('subject')->setLanguage($yourLanguage);
```

This problem occurs when subject have 2 and more different languages, where last word in English lang